# "string is undefined" de forma aleatoria

Tags: javascript

El siguiente script es un generador de nombres y apellidos aleatorios que funciona perfectamente.
El problema es que aleatoriamente me suelta que 'str' no está definido.

¿Alguien me puede aclarar que sucede y como solucionarlo?

```js
function capFirst(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function generateName(sexo){
    let hombre = ["antonio","jose","manuel","francisco","david","juan","javier","daniel"];
    let mujer = ["maria carmen","maria","carmen","josefa","ana maria","isabel","maria pilar","maria dolores","laura","maria teresa","ana","cristina"];
    let apellidos = ["garcia","gonzalez","rodriguez","fernandez","lopez","martinez","sanchez","perez","gomez","martin","jimenez","ruiz","hernandez","diaz","moreno","muñoz","alvarez","romero","alonso","gutierrez","navarro","torres","dominguez","vazquez","ramos","gil","ramirez","serrano","blanco","molina","morales","suarez","ortega","delgado","castro","ortiz","rubio","marin","sanz","nuñez","iglesias","medina","garrido","cortes","castillo","santos","lozano","guerrero","cano","prieto","mendez","cruz","calvo","gallego","herrera","marquez","leon","vidal","peña","flores","cabrera","campos","vega","fuentes","carrasco","diez","reyes","caballero","nieto","aguilar","pascual","santana","herrero","montero","lorenzo","hidalgo","gimenez","ibañez","ferrer","duran","santiago","benitez","vargas","mora","vicente","arias","carmona","crespo","roman","pastor","soto","saez","velasco","moya","soler","parra","esteban","bravo","gallardo","rojas"]
    let nombre;
    if (sexo == 'h')
        nombre = capFirst(hombre[getRandomInt(0, hombre.length + 1)]);
    else if (sexo == 'm')
        nombre = capFirst(mujer[getRandomInt(0, mujer.length + 1)]);
    else {
        if (getRandomInt(0,2) == 1)
            nombre = capFirst(hombre[getRandomInt(0, hombre.length + 1)]);
        else
            nombre = capFirst(mujer[getRandomInt(0, mujer.length + 1)]);
    }
    
    nombre += ' '+capFirst(apellidos[getRandomInt(0, apellidos.length + 1)])+ ' ' + capFirst(apellidos[getRandomInt(0, apellidos.length + 1)]);    
    return nombre;
}

for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    console.log(i+': '+generateName());
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El problema está en las líneas:

```
nombre = capFirst(hombre[getRandomInt(0, hombre.length + 1)]);
nombre = capFirst(mujer[getRandomInt(0, mujer.length + 1)]);
```

Puede darse el caso que se intente acceder a la posición `hombre.length+1` del array `hombre` por ejemplo, y este sea `undefined` porque no existe, y por lo tanto, no se puede ejecutar `charAt`

Comment: Tienes razón era un offset del array en toda regla.